# Subscribe to Event only works when component is loaded

Tags: angular, http, events

I have trouble handling data fetched from a Database. I'd like to send it to a central service in order to use it later when I load the components that will use the data.
My problem is that the central service only seems to receive the data when I initialize the component that depends on this service.
Consequence: the data is not ready yet when the component loads and I get this type of error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined

**Here is how my app is structured:**

-a dataStorage service which handles the http requests

-a central service which stores all the data (in that case, an array of objects).

-both a placed in a "shared" folder

-various components (with lazy loading) taking data from the central service

-the http request is sent when the app is initialized

Here is the data storage service. When the http request is made I send the data via an event in the constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
    constructor(private http:Http,private authService:AuthService){
      this.getStoredCatList().subscribe(
      (response:Response)=> {
             const data = response.json();
             this.dataFetched.emit(data);
        },
      (error:Error)=>console.log(error)
      );
  }

dataFetched = new EventEmitter<Cat[]>();


    getStoredCatList(){
        return this.http.get('https://adopt-meow.firebaseio.com/data.json');

    }
}
```

And here is the central service where I subscribe to the event.

```
@Injectable()
export class CatListService implements OnInit{

    constructor(private dataStorageService:DataStorageService){
        this.dataStorageService.dataFetched.subscribe(
            (catList:Cat[])=>this.catList = catList,
            console.log("event received by catList service"))
        }
```

From my understanding of Angular, I think I should get the message "event received by catList service" as soon as the event emits. So why do I get it only when I load the components?

EDIT
For those of you interested in following up that matter, I managed to find a solution by importing the services in app.component.ts, right when the app starts.

```
constructor(private dataStorageService: DataStorageService, 
    private catListService:CatListService) { }
```

Comment: Why do you have OnInit() for Service?

Comment: I previous mistake that I've just corrected

Comment: Your subscription gets active, only when `CatListService` is initialized. So I believe `CatListService` itself is initialized once your component is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Services` are initialized only when they are injected within the `Component` or any other `Service`. I believe you have injected `CatListService` within your components. And also the `subscription` that is made within the `CatListService` constructor will be active only once the service is loaded. That is why you are not receiving data before component loads.

**Note :** Providing `Service` at module level or component level will not invoke `Service` constructor. They are invoked only when you inject them in your `Component` or any other `Service` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit() is  a life cycle for  directives and components not with services, you can subscribe to your service inside a component or you can create an init method and call it inside the constructor of your service

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data is not yet loaded when you try to display it in your template.

U could try adding the `async` pipe where you are displaying the data.

```
<span>{{ genders | async }}</span>
```

That should avoid the error you are getting.